# Laravel doesn't support multiple form requests in the single controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I have single controller where I use different requests to validate data on each methods. I tried use requests with full namespace and by importing too but in both case doesn't work.

**For example**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\RegisterRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\PositionRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UserOrderRequest;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function register(\App\Http\Requests\RegisterRequest $request)
    {
        // do something
    }

    public function positions(\App\Http\Requests\PositionRequest $request)
    {
        // do something
    }

    public function user(\App\Http\Requests\UserRequest $request)
    {
        // do something
    }

    public function orders(\App\Http\Requests\UserOrderRequest $request)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

In this controller laravel can't found any Request file and return error with message:

> ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Requests[Name of Request] does
>   not exist in file
>   /home/c/website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteSignatureParameters.php
>   on line 25

**Example of my request file code**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            "name" => "required|min:3|max:100",
            "email" => "required|email|unique:users",
            "phone" => "required|numeric|unique:users",
            "positions" => "required|array|min:1|max:10",
            "positions.*.name" => "required|string|min:2|max:50|distinct",
            "password" => "required|min:8|string|max:255"
        ];
    }
}
```

**I tried commands:**

```
composer dump autoload

php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Laravel Framework: **6.17.0**

PHP: **7.4**

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but try

```
public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    //
}
```

You shouldn't need the full namespace as you've imported them already at the top.

Also make sure that you have the file UserRequest.php in the folder App\Http\Requests and that it's namespace matches

Answer (score 0):

What do the Request classes look like? What is in the files:

```
App\Http\Requests\UserRequest
App\Http\Requests\RegisterRequest
App\Http\Requests\PositionRequest
App\Http\Requests\UserOrderRequest
```

Ensure that the path and names of those files, the namespaces within those files, and the use statements you use in this file all match exactly. Case might matter depending on your server settings, so be certain capitalization matches.

Since you have use statements for them, you do not need to use the full namespace when injecting them.

```
   public function orders(UserOrderRequest $request)
    {
        // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;


class RegisterRequest extends Request
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            "name" => "required|min:3|max:100",
            "email" => "required|email|unique:users",
            "phone" => "required|numeric|unique:users",
            "positions" => "required|array|min:1|max:10",
            "positions.*.name" => "required|string|min:2|max:50|distinct",
            "password" => "required|min:8|string|max:255"
        ];
    }
}
```